# How to view Android bluetooth logs with btsnoop_hci.log?

Tags: android, bluetooth, wireshark, spp

I enabled developer options and bt snoop hci log to try and troubleshoot why the connection between my app and Bluetooth SPP device disconnects randomly. I took the bug report and emailed it to myself, and then opened the btsnoop_hci.log file using Wireshark.

I am trying to find the same event logs I might see in logcat, such as:

`W/bt_btm: btm_sec_disconnected`

but instead I have what just look like raw packets below. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

[image: Wireshark screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

> The files of interest are btsnoop_hci.log and all files with the extension .cfa
>
> These are binary files, which can be opened with Wireshark.

https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/How-to-capture-Bluetooth-traffic-from-and-to-an-Android-Device